# Display problems with end= '' and while loops. Want it to go to a new line when finished

Tags: python

With the display I want the Banking command: input to start on a new string but when it gets to the display elif it does not. I know why, its because of the end= '' but I need to have the display be in one line for the assignment and I cant figure out a solution. Thanks for the help.

```
def main():
    number_of_accounts = int(input("Number of accounts:\n"))
    accounts = [0.0] * number_of_accounts
    banking_command(accounts)

def banking_command(accounts):
    from os import _exit as exit

    active = True
    while active:
        banking_command = input('Banking command:\n')
        banking_command = banking_command.split(' ')

        if banking_command[0] == 'add':
            monetary_amount = float(banking_command[2])
            account_being_changed = int(banking_command[1])
            accounts[account_being_changed - 1] += monetary_amount

        elif banking_command[0] == 'subtract':
            monetary_amount = float(banking_command[2])
            account_being_changed = int(banking_command[1])
            accounts[account_being_changed - 1] -= monetary_amount
        elif banking_command[0] == 'move':
            monetary_amount = float(banking_command[3])
            transfer_money_out = int(banking_command[1])
            transfer_money_in = int(banking_command[2])
            accounts[transfer_money_out - 1] -= monetary_amount
            accounts[transfer_money_in - 1] += monetary_amount

        elif banking_command[0] == 'display':
            i = 0
            while i < len(accounts):
                account_number = i + 1
                print(str(account_number) + ":$" + str(accounts[i]) + " ", end= '')
                i += 1

        elif banking_command[0] == 'exit':
            exit(0)
```

main()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a print() after the while loop.

```
  elif banking_command[0] == 'display':
        i = 0
        while i < len(accounts):
            account_number = i + 1
            print(str(account_number) + ":$" + str(accounts[i]) + " ", end= '')
            i += 1

        print()  # <-- end the line with the account display
```